# Run python script on boot with serial enabled

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, barcode, startup

I have a python script that reads barcodes from a barcodescanner, I'm using the scanner via the serial usb interface. This always works when I run the script myself in the terminal.
But when I set the script in the rc.local file to run at startup the scanner won't work.

Is there a way to fix this or does anyone know whats the issue here?

I'm running the script on a raspberry pi model B3+

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a Cronjob that runs the script at start.
[https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: I've tried this for the root user & my personal user but my script doesn't start this way

Comment: did you mark your script as executable, chmod +x myscript.py